# Pip does not install in virtualenv

Tags: python, linux, pip

I've installed pip w/o system packages.

```
which pip
/home/pdaly/envs/py3/bin/pip

which python
/home/pdaly/envs/py3/bin/python
```

When I install via pip inside the virtualenv it seems to be using the system pip instead of the virtual env pip despite which pip pointing to the env.  I get the following error

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas-0.23.4.dist-info'
```

How do I fix this?

note: there are 20-30 people all using this machine installing packages directly to the system python...

```
(py3) pdaly@gpu01:~$ /home/pdaly/envs/py3/bin/python -c "import os, sys; print(os.linesep.join(sys.path))"
/home/pdaly/<private repo 1>/lib
/home/pdaly/<private repo 2>
/home/pdaly/<private repo 3>
/home/pdaly/envs/py3/lib/python35.zip
/home/pdaly/envs/py3/lib/python3.5
/home/pdaly/envs/py3/lib/python3.5/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu
/home/pdaly/envs/py3/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload
/usr/lib/python3.5
/usr/lib/python3.5/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu
/home/pdaly/envs/py3/lib/python3.5/site-packages

(py3) pdaly@gpu01:~$ echo $PYTHONPATH
/home/pdaly/<private repo 1>/lib/:/home/pdaly/<private repo 2>/:/home/pdaly/<private repo 3>/
```

Comment: What commands are you running that produce the PermissionError?

Comment: pip install pandas from within the env

Comment: I guess you did activate the venv before calling pip, but just notice it's trying to install on python2.7 dist lib, but you have a venv for python3.

Comment: @isydmr that's just a useless answer; he does not want to install on the system, but on this venv.

Comment: Can you run `/home/pdaly/envs/py3/bin/python -c "import os, sys; print(os.linesep.join(sys.path))" ` and add the output to the question? Also check whether you have `PYTHONPATH` env var set: `echo $PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: @hoefling updated

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned in one of the comments (kudos @mydaemon), the venv you're working with is a python3 environment, which is not compatible with python2 libs/scripts. In addition, if you didn't activate your environment, then any python scripts/tools will continue to run on the system python <s>(which looks like python2.7 in this case).</s>

<s>To get this working as python3, simply:</s> (**edit**: new info shows that this env is indeed an activated python3 env, so this won't work).

```
. ${HOME}/envs/py3/bin/activate
pip install panda
```

To use python2:

```
virtualenv --python=python2.7 ${HOME}/envs/py2
. ${HOME}/envs/py2/bin/activate
pip install panda
```

**Edit**: [Pandas on PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/pandas/) is a python 2.x library and will not work with pip on python3. The [Pandas website](http://pandas.pydata.org/) recommends installing via [anaconda](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/install.html)

Comment: If he uses Python 3, shouldn’t it be pip3 install pandas rather than pip install pandas?

Comment: In the comments above I stated I ran pip install from w/in the client just as you typed above.  The PermissionError is what I recieve when I run that.

Comment: @Alexis.Rolland @pmdaly: when the python3 env is activated the `pip` command is merely an alias for `pip3` ... it's referencing the script installed in the env. This is why you see the exact same error for both commands.